# Check whether a changed cell in a named range excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I just need to monitor changes in a worksheet, not in the whole worksheet, just inside a named range. So if any kind of change occurs in any cell it should check the change occurs in that named range and if so some function has to do.

**Here is my code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ir As Boolean

    ir = Application.Intersect(Target.Address, Range("bd_main"))
    If ir = True Then
        MsgBox "change"
    End If

End Sub
```

But it triggers an error saying `Type Mismatch` in the `Application.Intersect` function for `Target.Address`

What I did wrong there which causes such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slight modification, use the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("bd_main")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "change"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks mate.. it worked great.. I had a wrong belief that Application.Intersect returns bool type. But its Range itself.. isnt it?

Comment: @SandeepThomas  yep, it returns a Range object